# Catching Soap fault with custom object c#

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

[image: SoapFault]

I am a little confused on how to get the description & bad data part of this response.

I am able to capture the fault, but it's empty.

```
 catch (FaultException<EXLAPickup.EXLA.SoapError[]> SoapErrorCatch)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added DataContract to your Model?
For example, say the service contract is

```
  [ServiceContract]
  public  interface Test
 {
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(CalculatorFault))]
        double add(double a, double b);
}
```

Then DataContract should be add the type CalculatorFault.

```
 [DataContract]
public class CalculatorFault
{
    [DataMember]
    public string OperationName { get; set; }
   [DataMember]
    public string Fault { get; set; }

}
```